# How to exclude certain paths of xpath without getting scraped?

Tags: scrapy

I tried to **scrape** the data which is neccesary, but when I am trying to exclude the part which is not needed, I was unable to do that. Please help in scraping the data which is necessary?

Case - 1:

```
<div class="abc xyz">
      <div class="aaaaaa bbbbbb">
           "I dont want to include this"
      </div>
      ***"I just want to scrape this"***
</div>
```

Case - 2:

```
<div class="abc xyz">
      <div class="aaaaaa bbbbbb">
      </div>
      ***"I just want to scrape this"***
</div>
```

Both the cases, the output which I tried to get is "I just want to scrape this".

Already tried scraping using './/div[contains(@class,"abc")]//text()' - but in the first case it is giving output as "I dont want to include thisI just want to **scrape** this", In second case the expected output is scraped.

Answer (score 0):

This one will have some garbage in result, but it will do the job:

```
result = response.xpath('//div[@class="abc xyz"]/text()').extract()
result = "".join(result)
```

Comment: I dont want to include the content of inner div element.

Comment: It doesn't include it, for the first case result is '\n      \n      ***"I just want to scrap this"***\n'. However, as I've said, it includes some redundant new lines and spaces.

Comment: Output when I tried this is [u'n', u'I dont want to include this', u'I just want to scrap this.']

Comment: Just re-run it and received the same result as first time. Are you sure you copied correctly?

Comment: __scrape__ not __scrap__